# IONIC 4 Android 9 Background Mode PlugIn. Disable Battery Optimisation

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, background-mode

IONIC 4 BackgroundMode PlugIn is not disable battery optimisation.

I tested these solutions, but not working:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/430

I try to set:

```
  this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(()=>{
       this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();

      this.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations(); HERE

      console.log("background activate !!!!");
  });
```

But i get:

Property 'disableBatteryOptimizations' does not exist on type 'BackgroundMode'. Did you mean
'disableWebViewOptimizations'

Environment:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\Julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Julio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v11.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.7.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try this
First remove all the platforms, that is ios or android

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. ionic cordova platform rm ios

Now, add the following plugin,
 ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/tushe/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git

Then install the latest version of background-mode using 
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode@latest

Add your platforms again then retry.